# JQuery tabs, on tab select trigger event

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, tabs

I'm new with JQuery and I'm trying to make a tab select that triggers an event, this is the code that I created. But when I clicked on the tab that I want the event to trigger, the event do not trigger

```
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var selected = ui.panel.id;
            alert("Hello");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Create/iFrameStyling",
                data: { 'fontFamily': $('#ddlTypography').val() },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suspect the error is in your html (it would be good to post your html if the error persists). Here is a working fiddle with sample html. I suggest that you review your html.

http://jsfiddle.net/hvbnC/

Also, make sure that you include JQuery UI.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

html (sample, good format)

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>tab 1 ..sdfasfdsafd.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>tab 2 ..sdfasfdsafd.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>tab 3 ..sdfasfdsafd.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```